# Array copy fails in loop

Tags: c#, arrays

**Simplified Question:**

I want to use the following to build an html table dynamically.

```
   //table.Rows[row].Cells.AddRange(new TableCell[] { new TableCell(), new TableCell(), new TableCell(), new TableCell(), new TableCell(), new TableCell() });


for (int row = 0; row < intRows; row++)
{
    table.Rows.Add(new TableRow());
    table.Rows[row].Cells.AddRange(new TableCell[intCellsPerRow]);
    intTableRows = row;

}
```

I used the commented line before, but it is not flexible, so is not what I want.

The Line: `table.Rows[row].Cells.AddRange(new TableCell[intCellsPerRow]);`  does not work.

How can I get this to work?

**Answer** *Thanks to Heinzi*

```
  for (int row = 0; row < dtStructure.Rows.Count / TABLE_COLUMNS; row++)
            {

                table.Rows.Add(new TableRow());

                for (int i = 0; i < CELLS_PER_COLUMN * TABLE_COLUMNS; i++)
                {
                    table.Rows[row].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                }

                intTableRows = row;
            }
```

Comment: why wont you try foreach , if you can edut your question it would be nice i have problems to understand what you are trying to do .

Comment: I updated my answer to address your new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the *same* cells to all the rows. This is what happens: After the first iteration, the `(CELLS_PER_COLUMN * TABLE_COLUMNS)` cells you created have the first row as their parent. After the second iteration, their parent is changed to the second row, etc.. In the end, they all end up in the last row. Note that `ToArray` does *not* copy the cells, it just copies the *references* to the cells into a *new array*. So all the rows try to share the *same* cells, which does not work (a `WebControl` such as `TableCell` can only have a single parent).

For every row, you need to create *new* cells. I assume that you want something like this:

```
for (int row = 0; row < datatable.Rows.Count / 6; row++)
{
    table.Rows.Add(new TableRow());
    for (int i = 0; i < CELLS_PER_COLUMN * TABLE_COLUMNS; i++)
    {
        table.Rows[row].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
    }
}
```

Untested, since I don't have Visual Studio available right now, but you should get the idea...

**EDIT**: I just saw that you edited your question. Your line

```
table.Rows[row].Cells.AddRange(new TableCell[intCellsPerRow]);
```

does not work, because here you add an *empty* array of `intCellsPerRow` table cells, i.e., your array contains `{null, null, ...}`. You need to create each cell with `new` like in my code example above.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to do it the hard way!

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop is using a variable named `datatable` as a constraint. But inside your block,
you're adding the rows to a variable named `table`. Are these the same?

```
for (int row = 0; row < datatable.Rows.Count / 6; row++)  
{  
    TableCell[] arrCells = lCells.ToArray<TableCell>();  

    table.Rows.Add(new TableRow());  
    // Snip for brevity
}
```

Curious: What's with the `/ 6`? If you're just trying to get the rows into the table in order, why would you need to do this for every 6th row?

Comment: nope. table is the HTML object I need to build, while the dataTable is used as a sizecounter, coz the contents for the HTML table will come from the dataTable.

Comment: Well, then, that handily explains the /6. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most efficient, but the lazy in me would write it this way:

```
table.Rows[row].Cells.AddRange(
  new TableCell[intCellsPerRow].Select(c=>new TableCell()).ToArray());
```